# Where should I stop for interest to kids when driving between Toronto and Boston?

Tags: driving, toronto, boston, family

I'm planning on driving with my family (2 adults, 2 kids - 8 & 6yrs) from Toronto to Boston in August taking up to 2 days. Since we are not in a huge rush, we would like to visit some places along the way that the kids might be interested in - probably parks/museums/attractions etc.

Off the top of my head looking at the map Niagara Falls seems like a prime contender, but having never driven this route before I those with better knowledge and experience may have better ideas of alternative.

As far a a route goes, I can obviously get one from Google Maps, but vacation planning by algorithm will probably not produce be the most interesting of times, which is where this site and it's dedicated and knowledgeable users comes in. It's not always the most direct route which takes one to the most interesting places.

What is the best route that we should take and where should we stop on the way - you know, for the kids?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Any chance you could take a look at the [help] and then edit your question? Polling and asking subjective, broad questions are likely to get closed pretty quickly on Travel.  And 'best' for what? View? Speed? Convenient stops? Cellphone reception? Stop for what - views, cities, parks?

Comment: @MarkMayo Yes you're right I wasn't very precise. I've made some changes, does it now make for a better question?

Comment: At this point you click the 'reopen' button and the community takes care of the rest :)  It's more precise but still covers a rather large range of possibilities - will see what happens!

Comment: I would say it needs more precision. Between Toronto and Boston there are museums, parks worth visiting for at least a week maybe a month. What do you expect to find: historical, natural, any museum? there are also parks with mountains, but probably you can take a detour to the lake or ocean side.

Comment: If you get off the Thruway, you can find wineries, sailing/boating, NASCAR, the Corning Museum of Glass, prim college campuses, waterfalls, and so on— but a side trip into the Finger Lakes would add at least two or three hours of driving time, and there are a dozen different routes to take. It's still too broad to be answerable in a few paragraphs of text. I suggest consulting a guidebook first to see recommended routes and help narrow down your choices.

Comment: This is getting better. How about updating to include a map with your proposed route, and asking if you are going near something else worth stopping at. On the Niagara Falls front, a separate question about visiting it with school age children would probably do well.